Angular 14 : dynamic import of module on build
I want to share an Angular app that includes many modules.
I would allow users to choose which module to enabled in their project depending on their needs.
To do that, I have updated two files :
environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000',
  languages: ['fr', 'en'],
  defaultLanguage: 'fr',
  moduleConfigs: [
    {
      moduleName: 'auth',
      module: AuthModule,
      config: {},
      enabled: true,
    },
    {
      moduleName: 'calendar',
      module: CalendarModule,
      config: { numberOfEventsLimit: 3 },
      enabled: true,
    },
    {
      moduleName: 'cardsPage',
      module: CardsPageModule,
      config: { knownErrors: ['NO_PHOTO', 'NO_ACTIVE_CARD', 'UNPAID_FEES'] },
      enabled: true,
    },
    ...
  ]
}

app.modules.ts
const enabledModules = environment.moduleConfigs
  .filter(m => m.enabled)
  .map(m => m.module.forRoot ? m.module.forRoot(m.config) : m.module);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...enabledModules,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'environment', useValue: environment },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

The project works well on local dev server, but when I try to build in a specific env, e.g. ng build --configuration=production, I encounter the following compilation error:
Value could not be determined statically.
This seems to be due to the AOT compiler requiring the 'forRoot' value to be static.
When I disable aot in compilation options, the build succeeds.
Any ideas of how to work with this ?
